# Restrict Author to post only to a specific category

Tags: user-roles

I want to restrict authors to a specific Category to write in. A plugin that is suggested on many blogs is [restrict-author-posting](https://wordpress.org/plugins/restrict-author-posting/). Unfortunately, this is no longer maintained and was removed from the plugin store.

The only suitable but not a free plugin I found was PublishPress Pro. I really don't want to pay for that functionality.

An additional plus would be, that some editors can only publish in a certain category as well.

I am willed to write/edit some code if needed - I have experience with PHP etc but have never done something in WordPress itself. I could not find any post that solved it without the plugin I mentioned above.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:** I originally posted this question on r/Wordpress (https://new.reddit.com/r/Wordpress/comments/eyocc3/restrict_author_to_post_only_to_a_specific/)

Answer (score 0):

The plugin may no longer be maintained, but you can see the code at: https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/restrict-author-posting/trunk/restrict-author-posting.php

This can be used/modified under GNU General Public License to suit your needs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As I mentioned I do not have any experience with developing for Wordpress nether for developing plugins.

Isn't there another/easier way to fix this issue? I am wondering if no one else had this problem before because this does not sound like something special for me.

Comment: This site is here to help you do the work, not do the work for you. So you could create your own plugin using that one, of just copy the functions you need into your theme's functions.php file. You said you  can write PHP so this sounds like a nice little project for you to get your teeth stuck into wordpress development and that plugin appears to have most of what you need from a quick look.

Comment: Looks like you are righ - I was really looking for a quick-fix for my problem ;) . I will try to implement it my self now. I will update this question if I succeed.

Comment: Instead of trying to hack on an old plugin, you could create several custom post types instead. So for example if you have categories "apples" and "oranges," make an "apple" CPT and an "orange" CPT, and create your own capabilities for editing them. Then, you can give one user permission to create and edit "apple" CPTs but not "orange" CPTs, and vice versa, and you can still use a similar permalink structure to Posts in Categories.

Comment: @WebElaine I found this solution as well but some guys did not recommend it because this is causing a mess with your permissions (just quoting idk). I also thought that I could not use CPTs with Divi's (Theme) Blog Module. After some research I found that according to this Blog Post (https://www.peeayecreative.com/how-to-display-custom-post-types-in-the-divi-blog-module/) this is now possible with the new update. 

So I will try this in a few days and will keep updated this Question.

Answer (score 0):

On WordPress 6.1 I test restrict-author-posting and worked.

You can download restrict-author-posting from [this(1)](https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/restrict-author-posting.2.1.5.zip)   or [this(2)](https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/restrict-author-posting.2.1.5.zip) link and use this plugin.

Note: this plugin not work on Gutenberg and work fine with Classic Editor. for disable Gutenberg  editor you can use [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/classic-editor/).